# Minimally invasive low level PDF editor GUI

Tags: pdf, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a GUI to edit the low level PDF file structure without incremental updates and with the minimal changes possible to the PDF structure. For example, I would like the capability to perform a minimal edit like the following where only the `/Producer` is modified:

[image: Minimal editing on PDF]

It is worth noting that I've already tested iText Rups but it would produce a bigger change like this (or even worst for other PDFs):

[image: iText RUPS editing]

Comment: What is wrong with the iText RUPS after case? It looks like a minimal, non-incremental, change to me. At the end of a PDF is the xref table which contains the byte offsets of objects, so even a minimal change, especially one done at the beginning of a PDF binary data (which Producer often is) will require almost the entire xref table to be recalculated as the all the byte offsets from the beginning of the PDF file are off.

Comment: @Ryan, I didn't provide the best possible example. In this example iText RUPS was kind of preserving the structure (except for the changes in the Producer and the file identifier) because the PDF being modified was created with iText too. If it would have been created with another library the change produced by RUPS wouldn't be minimal.

Comment: I'm unaware of any tools that promise minimal changes. Why is minimal change a requirement for you? What is the issue if objects are moved around for instance?

Comment: I was looking for such a tool to help me identify the cause for an apparent Adobe Acrobat bug around digital signatures validation where I choose the approach of gradually and minimally modify the PDF structure until the bug was reproduced. See too https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/adding-verification-information-to-a-signed-pdf-makes-signature-validation-fail/m-p/12616303

Comment: Where is step (3) "And finally “Add Verification Information” for this signature." done? Where is this option located in Adobe? Screenshots would help a lot.

Comment: "Add Verification Information" is an action you can invoke by right clicking a digital signature without LTV status.